# Specialized Lazy support in AutoFixture for deferred instantiation

Tags: c#, autofixture

I am using `AutoData` with `AutoMoqCustomization` (the `InlineAutoMockData` attribute sets this up for me) to auto-inject constructor parameters for my SUT. One particular SUT has some business logic that happens in a constructor which requires the mocked & frozen injected dependencies to be set up prior to the constructor executing. My workaround right now is as follows (using Moq + NUnit3 + Autofixture):

```cs
[Test,
 InlineAutoMockData(DbPermissionsMode.ElevatedDefault, true),
 InlineAutoMockData(DbPermissionsMode.ReducedNoViewServerState, false)]
public void Enumerator_mappings_are_correct(
    DbPermissionsMode permissionMode, bool expectedBool,
    [Frozen] Mock<IProductConfigProvider> configProvider,
    IFixture fixture)
{
    configProvider.Setup(x => x.GetDatabasePermissionsMode(It.IsAny<bool>()))
                  .Returns(permissionMode);

    var vm = fixture.Build<CredentialsControlViewModel>()
                    .OmitAutoProperties()
                    .Create();

    vm.UseElevatedPermissions.Should().Be(expectedBool);
}
```

In this test, `CredentialsControlViewModel` invokes `IProductConfigProvider.GetDatabasePermissionsMode()` in its constructor. This workaround allows me to perform setup on the `configProvider` mock instance prior to constructing the `vm` variable using the injected fixture.

What would be more ideal to clean this up is something like this, which in my mind should be functionally the same:

```cs
[Test,
 InlineAutoMockData(DbPermissionsMode.ElevatedDefault, true),
 InlineAutoMockData(DbPermissionsMode.ReducedNoViewServerState, false)]
public void Enumerator_mappings_are_correct(
    DbPermissionsMode permissionMode, bool expectedBool,
    [Frozen] Mock<IProductConfigProvider> configProvider,
    [NoAutoProperties] Lazy<CredentialsControlViewModel> vm)
{
    configProvider.Setup(x => x.GetDatabasePermissionsMode(It.IsAny<bool>()))
                  .Returns(permissionMode);

    vm.Value.UseElevatedPermissions.Should().Be(expectedBool);
}
```

Here, I no longer use the `IFixture` directly. Instead, I want `Lazy<>` to behave as follows:

1. Internally create the given type (`CredentialsControlViewModel`) exactly as it would have been created if I instead passed in the parameter to the test as `CredentialsControlViewModel vm` (i.e. do it through Autofixture).
2. Propagate all of the attributes attached to `Lazy<>` to the type created by Lazy's factory function (append all of the customizations / specimen builders)
3. In all reasonable aspects, act as if I had done `[NoAutoProperties] CredentialsControlViewModel vm` directly, just within a factory function provided to `Lazy<>` instead of done immediately.

As a pseudo-code analogy, I would expect it to set up a `Lazy<>` from my earlier example like this:

```cs
var fixture = new Fixture().Customize(new AutoMoqCustomization { ConfigureMembers = true });
var lazy = new Lazy<CredentialsControlViewModel>(() =>
{
    return fixture.Create<CredentialsControlViewModel>();
});
```

I see that there's already a `LazyRelay`, but it doesn't do this, I think. I believe it just forwards the factory functionality to `Func<>`, but I still get a `MissingMemberException` from Lazy because there is no default constructor. [This blog post](https://megakemp.com/2011/08/01/anonymous-delegates-in-autofixture/) says that this should work, so I'm not sure what is going on.

I am happy to customize this if needed, I just don't know how to do that properly. AutoFixture customizations have a steep learning curve.

Could someone recommend a way to customize AutoFixture to get this behavior for Lazy? Note that I want this solution to be generic. I don't want to have to do a `fixture.Register()` for every closed type of `Lazy<>`.